# Bootstrap nav bar bottom of jumbotron is off set to the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have my navbar nested inside my jumbotron at the bottom. For some reason the navbar is offset to the right, I'm not sure how to get around this or why its happening? I have the feeling I'm just doing it all wrong? I'd like it to look and act very much like this navbar: https://michaelgrumley.com/ . This is the first time I'm messing with bootstrap. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```css
.jumbotron {
   background-image: url("https://image.jpg");
   background-color: #B3B3B3;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 550px !important;
   border-bottom: 8px solid #007595;
   
}

.logo {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 
}

header {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,65,98,.67);
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;

}

.logonav {
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   letter-spacing: 4px;
   margin-left: 25px;
   align-content: center;
}

a {
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

ul li a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover a {
   color: #80c0ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img class="img-fluid logo" src="the logo" alt="logo"/>
<header>
    <a href="">
        <h4 class="logonav">Title</h4>
    </a>
<ul class="nav">
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 2</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 3</a> </li>
    </ul>
</header>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screen-shot, this is the output you are looking for. See the CSS I added and I added `justify-content: center;` to your `.header`

```css
.jumbotron {
   background-image: url("https://image.jpg");
   background-color: #B3B3B3;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 550px !important;
   border-bottom: 8px solid #007595;
   
}

.logo {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,65,98,.67);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.logonav {
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   letter-spacing: 4px;
   align-content: center;
   margin-right: 2rem;
}

a {
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

ul li a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover a {
   color: #80c0ff;
}

.nav li {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 60px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img class="img-fluid logo" src="the logo" alt="logo"/>
<header>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="">
        <h4 class="logonav">Title</h4>
    </a>

<ul class="nav">
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 1</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 2</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tab 3</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

</header>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think I'm un clear on my question, so all the info in the navbar is just where i want it but the navbar itself is off set. Here is a link to what's happening, you can see the space from the edge of the page to where the navbar starts and continues off the page so that there is a scroll bar at the bottom of the page... how do i fix that?
https://stevesheppardbooks.com/Untitled-2.html

Comment: @Taryn So you're saying you want it to be the full width of the screen? No white margin?

Comment: yup and I actually figured out and found the answer to my question! I just needed to define the class as a row, problem solved